# On using nodemailer to send the email, receiving "ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined "

Tags: typescript, email, next.js, nodemailer

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io",
        port: 2525,
        auth: {
          user: "xxxxxx",
          pass: "xxxxxx"
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
          }
      });
    transport.sendMail()
      const mailData = {
        from: 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
        to: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
        subject: `Message From xxx`,
        text: 'xxxxx',
        html: `<div>Testing</div>`
       }
        transport.sendMail(mailData
        , (error, info) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
          }
        });
```

I have used the package "nodemailer" for sending the mail.
The service I used is mailTrap.

Using nodemailer, I have created the transporter using nodemailer.createTransport along with the mailtrap.io service credentials.

when i try to send mail using transporter.sendMail() I am receiving the following issue.

> ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined

The whole project has been created in NextJs Typescript. I need a solution to fix the above issue or other ways to send mail in Nextjs.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have created this nodemailer transport inside a index.tsx file.
Try using the same code inside a file that is being created under /pages/api/sendmail.ts.

You can get it works as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

setImmediate() is a browser API, so you are running nodemailer in a front-end context.
In my case, I was trying to run it in a Cypress end to end test using commands.

It needs to run in a back end context, so to work around this, I wrote my logic for the emailing in a function within an sendEmail.js file and called the function in the same file.

Then I executed it with a 'task' in Cypress, which is Node code, but I used the package 'exec' to run `node 'sendEmail.js` the script in it's own process.

```js
// sendEmail.js

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const sendMail = (to, subject, message) =>{
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", // hostname
        secureConnection: true,
        port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
        auth: {
            user: "your@email.com",
            pass: "yourpassword"
        },
    });

    const options = {
        from : "your@email.com", 
        to, 
        subject, 
        text: message,
    }

    transporter.sendMail(options, (error, info) =>{
        if(error) console.log(error)
        else console.log(info)
    })
}

sendMail('to-email', 'Subject', 'email body')
```

Then within your code, invoke it using the `path` and `exec` npm package

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

sendSuccessEmail() {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Adjust the path to your script
            const scriptPath = path.join(__dirname, './cypress/scripts/sendEmail.js');
            
            exec(`node ${scriptPath}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
              if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return reject(error);
              }
              console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
              console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
              resolve(stdout); // Resolve promise with the script's output
            });
          });
        }
```